# Python Pandas convert selective columns into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, backend

My dataset has some information about price and sales for different years. The problem is each year is actually a different column header for price and for sales as well. For example the CSV looks like

| Items | Price in 2018 | Price in 2019 | Price in 2020 | Sales in 2018 | Sales in 2019 | Sales in 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 120 | 135 | 5000 | 6000 | 6500 |
| B | 110 | 130 | 150 | 2000 | 4000 | 4500 |
| C | 150 | 110 | 175 | 1000 | 3000 | 3000 |

I want to show it something like this

| Items | Year | Price | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2018 | 100 | 5000 |
| A | 2019 | 120 | 6000 |
| A | 2020 | 135 | 6500 |
| B | 2018 | 110 | 2000 |
| B | 2019 | 130 | 4000 |
| B | 2020 | 150 | 4500 |
| C | 2018 | 150 | 1000 |
| C | 2019 | 110 | 3000 |
| C | 2020 | 175 | 3000 |

I used melt function from Pandas like this
df.melt(id_vars = ['Items'], var_name="Year", value_name="Price")

But I'm struggling in getting separate columns for Price and Sales as it gives Price and Sales in one column. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try pandas [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, i='Items', j='year', 
                stubnames=['Price', 'Sales'], 
                suffix=r'\d+', sep=' in ').sort_index()
```

---

```
              Price Sales
Items year              
A     2018    100   5000
      2019    120   6000
      2020    135   6500
B     2018    110   2000
      2019    130   4000
      2020    150   4500
C     2018    150   1000
      2019    110   3000
      2020    175   3000
```

Comment: What if I have few more columns for example Location, Country then how should I use this function for them as well those will remain same as Items. Thanks

Comment: @Suchi Add the corresponding columns in the `stubnames` list for e.g `stubnames=['Price', 'Sales', 'Country', 'Location']`

Comment: Would it work if I use Location and Country in stubname as that comes in two different columns like Items , So need to make changes in Location and Country columns.

Comment: I'm getting this error in wide_to_long
    raise ValueError("stubname can't be identical to a column name")

Comment: If you dont want to specify then as `stubnames` you can specify them as `id` variables. Please check `pd.wide_to_long(df, i=['Items', 'Country', 'Location'], j='year', stubnames=['Price', 'Sales'], suffix=r'\d+', sep=' in ').sort_index()`

Comment: Above is an example when I'm trying in the real datasets there are columns with 2015 Price per square ft  2015 Number of sales 2016 Price per square ft  ... 2018 Price per square ft  2018 Number of sales 2019 Price per square ft like this... what should I use in sep=' '

Comment: Let us [continue discussion here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234364/ds5)